# Unable to access string array in Shared Memory

Tags: c++, c, unix, operating-system

I am trying to send lines of text from a writer program to a reader program through shared memory. The writer works perfectly. However, during the execution of the reader program, I get a segmentation fault at the following line

`cout<<buffer->str[initial]<<endl;`

**The changes in count value of the shared structure are visible and correctly incremented when I run the reader simultaneously alongside the writer while commenting the above line. Hence, according to my diagnosis, the issue is with accessing the array of strings of the shared structure. Why is this the case ?**

The code consists of the writer.cpp and reader.cpp which have been provided below for reference.

The aim of the writer.cpp is to read lines from an input file and then write them in the shared memory.

**Writer.cpp**

```
// for c++ related functions
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

// for c related functions
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<unistd.h>

// for system calls
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
// for shared memory
#include<sys/shm.h>

using namespace std;

// store the key for accessing the shared memory
key_t shm_key = ftok("practical",65);

// the structure for shared memory
struct shared{
  bool the_end = false;
  int count = 0;
  string str[6];
};

int main(){

  // create the shared memory
  int shmid = shmget(shm_key,sizeof(shared),0666|IPC_CREAT);
  if(shmid == -1){
    perror("Error in creating shared memory");
    return 1;
  }

  // attach server to the shared memory
  struct shared *buffer = (shared*)shmat(shmid,NULL,0);
  if(buffer == (void *) -1){
     perror("Unable to attach to shared memory");
     return 1;
  }

  // open the file for reading the input
  ifstream fin("input.txt");
  // check for errors in opening the file
  if(!fin){
    cerr<<"Error in opening the file"<<endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  // to store the read line
  string inptxt;
  cout<<"Reading contents from file\n"<<endl;

  while(fin){
    // read a line
    getline(fin,inptxt);

    // exit the loop if string is empty
    if(inptxt == "\0") break;

    // store the line in the buffer
    buffer->str[buffer->count++] = inptxt;
    cout<<"This was written : "<<buffer->str[buffer->count-1]<<endl;

    sleep(3);
  }
  cout<<"Closing the file"<<endl;
  fin.close();

  // marks the end of writing into shared memory
  buffer->the_end = true;

  if(shmdt(buffer) == -1){
     perror("error in deatching from shared memory");
     return 1;
  }

  if(shmctl(shmid,IPC_RMID,0) == -1){
     perror("error in destroying the shared memory");
     return 1;
  }

  cout<<"Writing Completed"<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The aim of the reader program is to read lines from the shared memory and then display them on the console.

**Reader.cpp**

```
// for c++ related functions
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

// for c related functions
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<unistd.h>

// for system calls
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
// for shared memory
#include<sys/shm.h>

using namespace std;

// store the key for accessing the shared memory
key_t shm_key = ftok("practical",65);

// the structure for shared memory
struct shared{
  bool the_end = false;
  int count = 0;
  string str[6];
};

int main(){

  // create the shared memory
  int shmid = shmget(shm_key,sizeof(shared),0666|IPC_CREAT);
  if(shmid == -1){
    perror("Error in creating shared memory");
    return 1;
  }

  // attach server to the shared memory
  struct shared *buffer = (shared*)shmat(shmid,NULL,0);
  if(buffer == (void *) -1){
     perror("Unable to attach to shared memory");
     return 1;
  }

  cout<<"Reading contents from shared memory\n"<<endl;

  int initial = 0;
  while(!buffer->the_end){
    if(buffer->count > initial){
      cout<<"initial : "<<initial<<" buffer count : "<<buffer->count<<"\n";
      // the following line gives segmentation fault
      // cout<<buffer->str[initial]<<endl;
      initial++;
    }
  }

  if(shmdt(buffer) == -1){
     perror("error in deatching from shared memory");
     return 1;
  }

  cout<<"Reading Completed"<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is this to work if `std::string` allocates the string data from the heap at runtime?  The `sizeof(shared)` remains constant, since `sizeof` is a compile-time value.

Comment: You cannot put an `std::string` into a shared memory, only POD-types.

Comment: Why do you think a C++ `std::string` object will restrict itself to a specific location?

Comment: [This illustrates why this code will not work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed18bb267ab09e7b).  The `sizeof(shared)` remains at 200, regardless of the number of characters placed in one element of the string array.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I see the mistake now. The buffer space I allocate is fixed, whereas the memory for strings are being taken from heap, hence the segmentation fault.

Comment: And to add to the growing list of fundamental problems: like every other C++ class, `std::string` has a constructor. Which must be used for constructing ***every*** instance of the class. Creating a shared memory segment, and converting it to a pointer, just like that, is not going to result in its constructor being invoked, automatically. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: How should I go about correcting this ?

Comment: The best way to figure out how to do this correctly is to keep learning C++ and trying to understand how it works. How classes work. What a constructor and a destructor means. And so on. Once you have good, solid understanding of the core principles of C++ language itself, then you can branch out in operating system-specific topics like shared memory, that have nothing to do with C++, and figure out how to make everything fit together.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for the advice. I am aware of the basics of classes and related stuff, although I agree I need to work more on my C++ skills. However, a little direction into how to solve this problem would be appreciable so that I can figure out what is the best way to tackle this issue.

Comment: Until you have a firm grasp on things like custom allocators, the rule of thumb for you to follow, right now, is that the only thing you can put into shared memory are plain values and arrays. No classes like `std::string`. Basically, if it has a constructor, or a destructor, you can't have it in shared memory, and even for plain non-class data, you have to keep in mind that shared memory is not initialized, and you are responsible for clearing its contents to their initial values.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I was able to workaround this problem by using a character array with a fixed size. It would be nice if any one of you can answer this question along with this fix so that I can mark it accepted and close the question.